# Replace values in column based on other column

Tags: python, pandas

Using:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
a = pd.read_csv('Bvitoria_argos.csv', na_values=[' -99999.0'])
```

The dataframe is something like that:

```
HS   Tp
3.0  12.0
2.0  11.3
nan  19.2
nan  5.9
5.6  7.0
```

The objective is to replace values in ''Tp'' column based on ''HS'' values and get something like that:

```
HS   Tp
3.0  12.0
2.0  11.3
nan  nan
nan  nan
5.6  7.0
```

I've tried to use this, but it's not working:

```
c.loc[c.HS==np.nan,'Tp']=np.nan
```

To be more specifc, when is nan in ''HS'' column ''Tp'' column need to be nan to. Would be thankful if someone could help.

Answer (score 1):

Use `isnull()`:

```
df.loc[df['HS'].isnull(),'Tp'] = np.nan
```

Comment: Thanks, this works. Why my code c.loc[c.HS==np.nan,'Tp']=np.nan wasn't working?

Comment: np.nan == np.nan resolves as False, you need to use isnull()

Comment: thank you (: Just one more question, if i need to use this but with values higher or lower, for exemple, if i want to set nan in Tp if HS is higher than 5 how can i write this?

Comment: df.loc[df['HS'] > 5,'Tp'] = np.nan  Just as you expected.

Answer (score 0):

You could use np.where. If cond is a boolean array, and A and B are arrays, then

```
C = np.where(cond, A, B)
```

defines C to be equal to A where cond is True, and B where cond is False.

[Compare Indexing where condition.](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html)